# Sort Array of random numbers using insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insertion-sort

## Trouble Shooting My insertionSort

Here is my code...

```
        ArrayList<Integer> num2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int b = 0; b < 300; b++)
        {
            num2.add((int)(Math.random() * 1000));
        }
```

```
        if (choice == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Insertion Sort chosen\nUnsorted Array List: " + num2);
            insertionSort(num2);
            System.out.println("Insertion sorted Array List: " + num2);
        }//choice 2 end
```

```
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> num2)
{
    for(int f = 1; f < num2.size(); f++)
    {
        int key = num2.get(f);
        for (int g = f-1; g >= 0; g--)
        {
            if (key < num2.get(g))
            {
                num2.set(g+1, num2.get(g));
                if (g == 0)
                {
                    num2.set(0, key);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                num2.set(g+1, key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
Insertion Sort chosen 
Unsorted Array List: [42, 944, 500, 442, 277, 178, 881, 267, 705, 365, 481, 882, 221, 835, 329, 312, 97, 1,... 
Insertion sorted Array List: [1, 479, 479, 479, 479, 718, 785, 785, 988, 988, 988, 988, 988, 988, 988, 988, 988,... 
if anyone can help me figure out why a bunch of the larger numbers just start repeating themselves because it is frustrating.

Comment: I think it's the right time for you to learn the wonderful world of debugging!

Comment: `break` out of the inner loop after you've put `key` in its proper spot.

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot find where the problems is, you can make use of the breakpoint to help you. Set one or several breakpoints where you think the codes here are critical. For example, when you debug your `insertionSort` function, you can set your breakpoint at Line 5 to see what changes the inner loop have made on your array. And you will find that the inner loop have done something outside your expectation. Then you can continue to set the breakpoint inside the inner loop to see where the problem is.

Actually, your problem is that when you find the right position to put your `key`, you should break the inner loop. Otherwise, since the `key` is larger than all the numbers before the proper position, all the numbers before except the first one (since your code is `num2.set(g+1, key);`, and when g = 0, it changes the second element) will be replaced by the `key`.

So, you only need to add a `break`.

```java
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Integer> num2)
{
    for(int f = 1; f < num2.size(); f++)
    {
        int key = num2.get(f);
        for (int g = f-1; g >= 0; g--)
        {
            if (key < num2.get(g))
            {
                num2.set(g+1, num2.get(g));
                if (g == 0)
                {
                    num2.set(0, key);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                num2.set(g+1, key);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```